# Стек на основе динамического массива, с++

Tags: c++, массивы, стек

Я пытался реализовать на си++ стек с помощью динамического массива. В приведенном ниже фрагменте реализация метода push. Просто создаю динамический массив на 1 элемент больше, копирую его со старого, удаляю старый массив и его указателю присваиваю новый массив. Однако в основной программе в cout выводится мусор, причем вместо первых 3 элементов(которые заданы константно) тоже мусор.
В рамках отладки выводил массив stack в конце функции, все показывает правильно...

Скажите пожалуйста, что здесь не так? И можно ли как-то обойти эту проблему? Спасибо.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void push(int *stack, int size, int a)
{
int *new_stack = new int[size + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
new_stack[i] = stack[i];
delete[] stack;
stack = new_stack;
stack[size] = a;
};

int main()
{
int *stack = new int[3];
stack[0] = 6;
stack[1] = 3;
stack[2] = 7;

push(stack, 3, 5);
for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
cout « stack[i] « " ";

delete[] stack;
}
```

Comment: `stack = new_stack` вы изменили временную переменную, а не ту, что передали в функцию.

Comment: Приведите [mre], чтобы можно было у себя запустить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void push(int *stack, int size, int a)
```

ваша ошибка вот тут

вы удаляете массив `stack` и создаете новый `new_stack`, но вы можете новый передать только внутри своей функции, для того, чтобы изменять переменные ВНЕ функции, надо передавать их в функцию по ссылке:

```
void push(int* &stack, int size, int a)
```

или как вариант - передавайте указатель на ваш массив (т.е. на указатель)

```
void push(int** stack, int size, int a)
```

правда тогда с ним придется работать чуть по другому

```
new_stack[i] = *stack[i];
```

и

```
push(&stack, 3, 5);
```

что не очень то удобно и наглядно и для c++ лучше уж использовать ссылки

**P.S.**

вообще если вы часто будете вставлять новые элементы, то система офигеет выделять и удалять память, производительность такого кода будет нулевой

лучше делать так:

1. обернуть ваш массив в структуру у которой будет поля - указатель на массив, размер массива, максимальный размер массива

   ```
    struct myarray {
        int* array = nullptr;
        int  size = 0;
        int  capacity = 0;
    }
   ```
2. когда вам надо добавить новый элемент вы проверяете - а `size < capacity` и если да, то просто увеличиваете `size` на 1 и  задаете значение нового элемента
3. если `size == capacity`, то вы создаете новый массив размером `capacity * 2` (ну или массив большего размера на полтора, на 20% или еще на что-то, что способно выдержать несколько операций записи без выделения и удаления памяти)
4. ну и копирование из массива в массив лучше не с помощью поэлементного копирования, а через `memcpy(new_arr, arr, sizeof(int) * size)`

Answer (score 1):

Оставим в стороне неэффективность вашего подхода...

Итак,

```
void push(int *stack, int size, int a)
...
stack = new_stack;
```

Этим вы заменили только лишь *копию*, переданную в функцию, но не само значение переменной: после

```
push(stack, 3, 5);
```

значение `stack` остается тем же.

Раз у вас C++ - передавайте указатель по ссылке:

```
void push(int*&stack, int size, int a)
```

тогда переданная переменная "почувствует" изменения, сделанные в функции.